# Get the last id of an array

Tags: react-native

I have an array. If I press on any item of this array will take me to a different page by "Actions", but if I click on the last item in this array, I want to call a function NOT pushing to a page!? How can I do that?

```
const routes = [
  { icon: "home", slide: "Home" },
  { icon: "profile", slide: "Profile" },
  { icon: "staro", slide: "Favorites" },
  { icon: "wechat", slide: "Chats" },
  { icon: "setting", slide: "Setting" },
  { icon: "infocirlceo", slide: "About App" },
  { icon: "logout", slide: "Log Out" }
];
 renderRow={data => {
              return (
                <ListItem button onPress={Actions[data.slide]}>????????
                  <View style={{ marginRight: 20 }}>
                    <AntDesign name={data.icon} style={{ fontSize: 30 }} />
                  </View>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 20 }}>
                    {data.slide}
                  </Text>
                </ListItem>
              );
            }}
```

This is the function I want to call:

```
_handleLogOut = () => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('user');
    alert('You have been logged out.');
}
```

Comment: All items in Array calling inside <ListItem onPress=doSomthing>?

Comment: Yes>>>exactly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if statement to handle it

```
<ListItem button onPress={route.icon =="logout" ?this._handleLogOut : otherAction} 
...
 />
```

Comment: that worked  >>onPress={data.slide =="Log Out" ?this._handleLogOut : Actions[data.slide] ,,,thank you